# How to evaluate $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

It's a very simple question but it confuses me. How do I evaluate
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}~dx
$$
without splitting? And why can't I split it?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, because $x\mapsto \frac 1 x$ is not in $L_1$ and thus cannot be integrated over $[1,\infty)$ (as a matter of fact $\int_{[1,\infty)}\frac {dx} x = +\infty$).

However, $\frac 1 x-\frac 1 {x+1}$ can be rewritten (by reducing to the same denominator) into something which is in $L_1$ (and whose integral is easy to compute).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want

$$\begin{align}\int_1^{\infty} dx \left ( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right ) &= \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_1^{R} dx \left ( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right ) \\ &=\lim_{R \to \infty} [\log{R} - (\log{(R+1)} - \log{2})]\\ &= \log{2}  \end{align}$$

Comment: Look at the edited version! It’s $x+1$ instead of $x-1$.

Comment: How did you get to step 2. Can you elaborate a little more about how we reached to log R - ( log (R+1))  - log 2 ?

Comment: $$\int dx \frac{1}{x+a} = \log{(x+a)} + C$$

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compute the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x + 1}$ by substitution.  Then, you get logarithmic function.  But it is not defined at $\infty$.  Note that:

$$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx - \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x + 1} dx$$
$$= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_1^t \frac{1}{x} dx - \int\limits_1^t \frac{1}{x + 1} dx$$

For the second integrand, use substitution, letting $u = x + 1 \rightarrow du = dx$.  Then:

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_1^t \frac{1}{x} dx - \int\limits_1^t \frac{1}{u} u$$
$$= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \ln{x} - \ln{u}|_{x = 1}^t$$
$$= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \ln{x} - \ln{x + 1}|_{x = 1}^t$$
$$= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \ln{t} - \ln{1} - (\ln(t + 1) - \ln(1 + 1))$$

So if we substitute $t$ with $\infty$, then we obtain the diverging integral.

Comment: Well you split the integral into two different integrals. Is that allowed?

Comment: @NasuSama : You get the idea but your technique is not right. You can't split the integral after computing the limit, you need to split it before. In other words,
$$
\int_1^{\infty} \left( \frac {1}{x} - \frac {1}{x+1} \right) \, dx = \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \left( \frac 1x - \frac 1{x+1} \right) \, dx = \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(  \int_1^t \frac 1x \, dx - \int_1^t \frac 1{x+1} \right) \, dx.
$$
and you can compute that limit by evaluating the two integrals.

Comment: But you need to see that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(  \int_1^t \frac 1x \, dx - \int_1^t \frac 1{x+1} \right) \, dx \neq \lim_{t \to \infty}  \int_1^t \frac 1x \, dx - \lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \frac 1{x+1}  \, dx 
$$
because those limits on the RHS do not exist (i.e. aren't real numbers). Also, your integral on $u$ should be written 
$$
\int_2^{t+1} \frac 1u \, du
$$
because you need to make the change of variables on the integral's bounds too. If you simplify everything the integral will be convergent.